# BitArray Thread Safety

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, thread-safety, bitarray

I am looking for information regarding the thread-safety of concurrent writes to the `System.Collections.BitArray` class.

Specifically, consider the following contrived example:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(1000000);

Parallel.For(0, bits.Count, i =>
{
    bits[i] = i % 3 == 0;
});
```

Instinct tells me that concurrent unlocked access would produce an incorrect result **if two threads attempt to write to the same underlying integral value of the bitarray**, yet I can not find any evidence to support it, and I have not encountered any problems during runtime.

Is this a safe operation?

If not, why am I not seeing this code fail or produce incorrect output?

### Update

After further testing, I think the following test proves that using a `BitArray` in this example is **not** thread safe.

Using a `bool[]` on the other hand, does seem to be safe.

```
private static bool CompareBitArrays(BitArray a, BitArray b)
{
    if (a.Count != b.Count) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numElements = 1000000;

    //create single-threaded bitarray with certifiably correct values.
    BitArray controlGroup = new BitArray(numElements);
    for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        controlGroup[i] = i % 3 == 0;
    }

    //create a BitArray and bool array of equal size and fill them using Parallel.For.
    BitArray bits = new BitArray(numElements);
    bool[] bools = new bool[numElements];

    Parallel.For(0, numElements, i =>
    {
        bits[i] = bools[i] = i % 3 == 0;
    });

    //Create a BitArray from the bool array
    BitArray boolBits = new BitArray(bools);

    //Check if they contain correct values
    bool isBitArrayCorrect = CompareBitArrays(controlGroup, bits); //FALSE
    bool isBoolArrayCorrect = CompareBitArrays(controlGroup, boolBits); //TRUE
}
```

As I mentioned, I suspect the reason to be that 32 values in the `BitArray` share the same integral value of the array.

Is this logic correct?

*For the sake of question, please assume no threads other than those shown in the code are accessing the collection.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into `BitArray.Set` method code:

```
public void Set(int index, bool value)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_Index"));
    }
    if (value)
    {
        this.m_array[index / 32] |= 1 << index % 32;
    }
    else
    {
        this.m_array[index / 32] &= ~(1 << index % 32);
    }
    this._version++; // this is definitely thread-unsafe
}
```

As far as you accessing collection member by index, without enumerating it, the only thread-unsafe line of code I see there, is the last line `this._version++;`.

But it is there, so, you can consider this code as thread-unsafe.

Comment: Wouldn't you say the bit changing methods are unsafe? Please see updated test in question. How do you explain the results?

Comment: @Rotem: Bit changing method `BitArray.Set` is unsafe, because it uses shared state (`_version` field). This is in my post. What to explain the results for?

Comment: I asked because in your answer you wrote the only unsafe part is `_version++`.

Comment: @Rotem: that's right. Because without `_version++` `BitArray.Set` is just a wrapper for your `bools[i] = i % 3 == 0`.

Comment: The |= or &= operations are not atomic, so it is unsafe regardless of the _version

Answer (score 2):

I think this quote from MSDN under [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) should tell you everything you want to know:

> This implementation does not provide a synchronized (thread safe)
>   wrapper for a BitArray.
>
> **Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure**. Even when a collection is synchronized, other threads can
>   still modify the collection, which causes the enumerator to throw an
>   exception. *To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can
>   either lock the collection during the entire enumeration* or catch the
>   exceptions resulting from changes made by other threads.

I have bolded the important bit.  Any enumeration through the collection is not thread safe, any altering of elements is therefore also not threadsafe, you should lock the entire collection or use one of the Thread safe collections.  (Though I'm not sure a BitArray exists)

Comment: Is this really relevant even if no modifications to the collection are being made? i.e. no items removed or added.

Comment: If the collection is not changed (immutable), I guess you should not worry about the thread safety.

Comment: @Int3ὰ as far as I can tell, OP is writing to the collection in the `Parallel.For`  loop.  The result of the ((i % 3) == 0) is being written to `Bit[i]` int the collection.  So that's a modification, which requires synchronization.

Comment: @Rotem: Enumerating a collection is not a threadsafe operation, so if you want to be on the safe side, you go with thread synch, because you never know that some other thread may be doing things to your collection at the same time.  I guess unless you're absolutely sure the collection will not be enumerated at the same time by any other thread, then you won't need synch.

Comment: @Int3ὰ would you claim that a `bool[]` array would be equally unsafe?

Comment: @Rotem yes, it would be unsafe.

Comment: @Tony using `Parallel.For`, which is a blocking method, pretty much ensures that no other threads are accessing the collection.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: he doesn't *enumerates* collection. He accesses its elements by index, without creating any enumerator.

Comment: @Dennis the for loop "enumerates" (as in goes through) the collection.

Comment: @Tony AFAIK that is not enumeration. No enumerator is used.

Comment: Still goes through the collection.  Still modifies the collection. Also, I can't find any evidence of your claim that `Parallel.For` ensures that the collection can not be accessed when it is enumerating the collection?  Can you show me where you found that?

Comment: @Tony My wording was mistaken. What I meant to say is that *I* am not accessing the collection from any other threads. For the sake of the question let's assume no one else is either.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: *enumeration* means access through the `IEnumerator` instance. Used `Parallel.For` overload doesn't create any `IEnumerator` for source collection. The line from MSDN you've marked is related to access via `IEnumerator` instances.

Comment: @Rotem right. Well, you were asking if it's a safe operation. Because you're changing things in the collection, and because it's in a multithreaded env, it's unsafe. However, I don't know what the rules are with `Parallel.For`. I don't know what guarantees it makes.

Comment: @Dennis I get your point. Still, he's going through the collection and altering it, AFAIK that's not a thread safe operation, without synch.

Comment: @Tony `Parallel.For` is not the issue. This could just as well be any other form of multi-threading. What I meant is we should assume no other threads outside of the example code are accessing the collection.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a ThreadSafeBitArray class that performs better than a regular lock over BitArray class. Maybe someone will find it useful.

```
public class ThreadSafeBitArray
{
    private static int[] _cachedShifts;

    static ThreadSafeBitArray()
    {
        _cachedShifts = new int[32];

        for (int index = 0; index < 32; index++)
        {
            _cachedShifts[index] = ((int)1 << index);
        }
    }

    private int _length;
    private int[] _arr;

    public ThreadSafeBitArray(int length)
    {
        _length = length;
        _arr = new int[ToUnderlineLength(length)];
    }

    private int ToUnderlineLength(int length)
    {
        int underlineLength = length / 32;

        if (length % 32 != 0)
        {
            underlineLength++;
        }

        return underlineLength;
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
    }

    public bool this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _arr[index >> 5], 0, 0) & (_cachedShifts[index & 31])) != 0;
        }
        set
        {
            int prevValue;

            if (value)
            {
                do
                {
                    prevValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _arr[index >> 5], 0, 0);
                }
                while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _arr[index >> 5], prevValue | (_cachedShifts[index & 31]), prevValue) != prevValue);
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    prevValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _arr[index >> 5], 0, 0);
                }
                while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _arr[index >> 5], prevValue & ~(_cachedShifts[index & 31]), prevValue) != prevValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear, fabulous and simple. Thanks. I add to favourites for my open source neural networks layer neuron mask